# Getting valid Timezone and keyboard language lists in linux

Tags: linux, command-line, ubuntu

I'm currently working on a project where I need to give the user the ability to select a timezone and a keyboard layout. My approach to this would be to give them the options in the traditional way ie: via a combo box. However After having difficulty in obtaining valid timezone options and keyboard language options from the command line I'm wondering if such commands exist, or if there is even a way to get these lists without having to trail through the directories and retrieve them one by one.

Any help or clarification on this would be appreciated.

For completeness: i'm working on ubuntu 10.04.

Cheers

Chris